# How to propagate signal in C from parent to child which are in own process group?

Tags: linux, process, signals, sigint

Suppose I have 10 child processes which are moved to their own process group by setpgid(0,0) just before the exec. (Each child also has children which are also in their own process group.)
My foreground process gets ctrl-c SIGINT signal and I want to propagate it to the all child processes (all children are in different group). How to do that?

hope that quick draft better explain my problem.

```
void handler(int signal) {
// resend SIGINT to all childs but childs are in different pgid
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

struct sigaction sa;
sa.sa_handler = &handler;

sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL);

pid_t pid[SIZE];

int i = 0;
// if argv is ge 2; 
for (;i < SIZE; i++) // SIZE is number of the elements in argv
{
   pid[i] = fork();
   if(pid[i] == 0)
   {
      setpgid(0,0);
      // execv self here but with one less element in argv;
   }
}
while(1){}; // infinity loop (waits for ctrl-c from foreground process)

// prints to the terminal pid and pgid
// waits here for all childs to finish and then close self
}
```

Comment: Let each parent send a `SIGINT` to each of its children?

Answer (score 0):

What about forwarding the signal in the signal handler of main process, manually. Maybe you can provide some code snippet to clarify the situation you're in.

```
void signalHandler(int signum)
{
  kill(child_pid,signum);
  //other stuff
}
```